# Nginx CentOS 7 yum Install Error

Tags: centos, installation, centos7, yum

I am trying to install Nginx on centOS 7 but I keep getting this error

```
[nginx error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwMhQ.png


Things I have tried:
-Yum Clean All

-Installed Epel-release 

-Tried to install apt-get,wget, and unzip but receive the same errors

- created a yum repo for nginx with the following:
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl= ht tp://n ginx.org /packages/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

- sudo yum -y install nginx httpd-tools

- sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

If anyone knows how I can get around this or knows an alternate way to install ELK Stack on centos7 that will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please format your question properly. For starters, make sure the image is **viewable** (or if it's possible, just post the console/error logs as text).

Comment: Are really some spaces in baseurl as I can see a few? Like 'ht tp' and two more spaces there in the same line. There should not be any space.

Answer (score 1):

In particular to installing Nginx on CentOS 7, not sure of what kind of error you have (could not open the image/picture from you), but just tried (around 10 minutes ago) on CentOS 7 (Vagrant Box "CentOS-7.2-1.8T"), it worked with the following simple 2 steps:

1. sudo yum -y install epel-release

2. sudo yum -y install nginx

It worked without running "yum clean all" and without creating "/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo".

If httpd-tools is needed, it also worked by adding an extra (separate) command "sudo yum -y install httpd-tools".

Not sure if this is the solution or whether this is helpful enough, but just looking at what you have tried, I just want to share that even simpler steps seem sufficient enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

name=nginx repo -> name=nginx

## yum-config-manager --enable nginx

## yum install nginx httpd-tools

[nginx stable version install on CentOS 8](https://www.runit.cloud/2020/01/nginx-stable-mainline.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing ngnx on centos7,you need to add the repository using epel release. We need to add the repo first then we can start installing .

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Then we can edit repo

```
$frugalis vi /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

Now add the below

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=https://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

This will enable the repo .. For installations on any other OS Versions , you can add repo going to their official website [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) .Trick is you need to enable the repo based on the versions . Then you can follow [next steps](https://thelinuxterminal.com/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos7/)  like Configuring selinux or enabling firewall.